# How to add comment on django site with ajax call and without refreshing?

Tags: django, ajax, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

On site exists form where users able to comment products. Comments are connected with products. jQuery is used from Bootstrap base.html (it's worked with another ajax-call). I'm fighting with ajax comment during the week). Trying to do it only for one product to understand how it works. Without ajax system of comments works fine, but I decided to add smooth in comment add without refreshing of the page and I do task with POST and ajax for the first time (before I did two pretty simple examples with get and form reset after successful response to ajax from back-end). Could somebody advice what should be add in template and view ? I suppose problem is connected with my poor knowledge of js.

I am using

```
is_ajax = request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

because this is working with django 4.0, and old function `is_ajax()` was removed.

views.py

```
def ajax_test(request):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=4)
    comments = product.comment_set.order_by('-created_at')
    form = UserCommentForm

    context = {'product':product,'comments':comments,'form': form}
    return render(request, 'store/ajax_test.html', context)

def ajax_receiver(request):
    is_ajax = request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
    if request.method == 'POST' and is_ajax:
        product = Product.objects.get(id=4)
        form = UserCommentForm(data=request.POST)
        user = Comment.objects.get(author=user)
        if form.is_valid() and request.user.is_authenticated:
            new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.author = request.user
            new_comment.product = product
            new_comment.save()
            comment_info = {
            "author": new_comment.author,
            "new_comment": new_comment.content,
            "created_at": new_comment.created_at,
            }
            return JsonResponse({"comment_info": comment_info}, status=200)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"success": False}, status=400)
```

template

```
{% extends "store/base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}

{% block page_header %}
  <h1>тестирую аякс</h1>
{% endblock page_header %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
     <div class="row py-3">
         <div class="col-3 order-2" id="sticky-sidebar">
           <div class="sticky-top">
             <form id="UserCommentForm" method='post' class="form">
               {% csrf_token %}
               {% bootstrap_form form %}

               {% buttons %}
                 <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="comment">Добавить комментарий</button>
               {% endbuttons %}
           </form>
         </div>
       </div>
    <div class="col" id="main">
      <h3>Комментарии:</h3>
       {% for comment in comments %}
       <h6 class="card-header">
       {{ comment.author }}<small> добавлен {{ comment.created_at|date:'M d, Y H:i' }} </small>
       </h6>
        <div class="card-body">
        <h4>{{ comment }}</h4>
        <form action="" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}


         </form>

        </div>
        {% empty %}
        <p>Для данного товара  ещё нет комментариев.</p>

        {% endfor %}

              </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% block javascript %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#UserCommentForm").submit(function(e) {
          // prevent from normal form behaviour
          e.preventDefault();

          // serialize the form data
          var serializedData = $(this).serialize();

          $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url :  "{% url 'store:ajax_receiver' %}",
                data : serializedData,
                success : function(response){
                
                    ??? what should be there to post ???
                },
                error : function(response){
                    console.log(response)
                }
            });
       });
    });
    </script>
    {% endblock javascript %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Finally I found the decision, it's just to reload block of comments without refreshing, there is the code, the space before ' #main' is important!:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#UserCommentForm").submit(function(e){
        // prevent from normal form behaviour

            e.preventDefault();
            // serialize the form data


            var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url :  "{% url 'store:ajax_receiver' %}",
                data : serializedData,
                success : function(response){
                    $('#main').load(' #main', function(){
           /// can add another function here

      });
                    $("#UserCommentForm")[0].reset();

                },
                error : function(response){
                    console.log(response)
                }
            });
       });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ajax success write the following code to show new comment:

```
let comment_info = response["comment_info"];
let author = comment_info["author"];
let comment  = comment_info["comment"];
let created_at = comment_info["created_at"];
html = "<h6 class='card-header'> "+author+"</h6>"
// i have writting only part of html write the full just like you do when you show comments
$("#main").append(html);
```

Comment: Thank you! I got your point, but I'm afraid I stucked with one another problem before this part, I can not receive author of the comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70540065/how-to-get-user-with-post-ajax-call-in-django

Comment: I could not realize it and found one better decision. I added it in my question, anyway thanks!

Comment: @Алексейsk1p you mark this answer as accepted if it helped you

Comment: Sorry, I'm newbie there, I didn't know, I marked.